# What is the probability that water will arrive to its destination?

Tags: probability

I have the following picture:

[image]

> A, B, C, D are all INDEPENDENT stations pumping water so that water
> arrives at L, the probability of each one of them working is written
> under them. Water arrives if we can get an entire "line" of stations
> working. What is the probability that water arrives to L?

Now in the solution given the author does the following:

P(System works)=$P(A\cap B \cap (C \cup D))$

then proceeds by saying $P(C\cup D)=P(C)+P(D)-P(C\cap D)$

Now my question is: how is that correct? namely, this doesn't take into account all stations working (we remove $P(C\cap D)$) which is one of the possible cases the system works.

For the system to work we need one of these 3 cases to happen:

1.$A\cap B\cap C \cap D'$
2.$A\cap B\cap C' \cap D$
3.$A\cap B\cap C \cap D$

It looks to me like the author didn't take into account the third option, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The third option is accounted for. Remember that you subtract $P(C\cap D)$ because it is counted twice in $P(C) + P(D)$.

Comment: how did I miss this, my bad, thank you]

Comment: Author did account for it. $P(C \cup D) = ((P(C) - P(C \cap D)) + ((P(D) - P(C \cap D)) + P(C\cap D)$

Comment: thank you everyone -)

Answer (score 1):

A and B are connected in Series, while C and D are connected in Parallel

Thus the system will work only if

- A and B both work, $p_1=0.9\times 0.9$

AND

- At leas one of C and D works, $p_2=1-0.2\times 0.2$

Concluding

$$p=p_1\cdot p_2=0.7776$$

This is exactly the same solution of your textbook